# Gradle: run a specific java class

Tags: gradle

My gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "com.example.Main"

project.buildDir = 'target'
version = '0.1'

jar{
    destinationDir=project.buildDir
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

When I want to run, I type `gradle run` and it will execute com.example.Main class. I was wondering if there is a mechanism to execute specific class without changing the build.gradle. What I ultimately want is something similar to `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`, where you can specify the main class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set gradle project properties with -P, for example:

gradle run -PclassToExecute=com.myClass

and in the script:

mainClassName=classToExecute

Answer (score 1):

If you change your build script to:

```
mainClassName = System.getProperty("exec.mainClass") ?: "default.Main"
```

You can execute a particular class with: `gradle run -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Main`